# Duda sobre los arrays y los bucles for

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

```
 for (let x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
        let y = a.filter((v) => v == a[x]);
        if ( y.length == 1 ) {
            return a[x];
```

En la linea `let y = a.filter((v) => v == a[x])`; estoy diciendo que `v` va a tomar el valor temporal de cada elemento escaneado en ese instante por el bucle for o que va tomar el valor de todos los elementos del array por separado?

Porque, según veo en el código, esta función revisa que cada elemento del array tenga un gemelo para retornar el valor diferente y para esto, se utiliza el método `filter` que tiene por parametro `v` que se convierte en función anónima y luego verifica mediante `==` que el valor exista o no en el array.

**La pregunta central** es, cuando escaneo el array, se toma cada valor de manera individual y temporal o la variable x toma en cuenta todos los elementos del array al momento de hacer la comparación?

Comment: filter recorre cada elemento del array haciendo la comparacion con la variable a[x] y asi en cada iteracion del for vuelve a recorrer todo el array en filter. Por lo que se toma cada valor de manera individual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes comprobar el comportamiento añadiendo algunas líneas `console.log(...)` en el código:

```js
const array = [0,0,1,1,2,3];
function test(a) {
  for (let x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
    console.log("x es",x);
    let y = a.filter((v) => {
      console.log("v es",v);
      console.log("a[x] es",a[x]);
      return v == a[x];
    });
    console.log("y es", y);
    if ( y.length == 1 ) {
        return a[x];
    }
  }
}

console.log(test(array));
```

Como puedes ver:

- La función que le pasas a filter se ejecuta para cada elemento del array, por lo que v tendrá en cada ejecución el valor correspondiente del elemento a comprobar.
- Siempre va a pasar que el N-ésimo elemento del array es igual a sí mismo, por lo que todas las llamadas a filter devolverán un elemento, al menos.
- Puesto que sólo paramos el bucle cuando hemos encontrado un único elemento, esta función lo que hace es devolver el primer elemento no repetido del array, en este caso el 2.

Comment: Soy consciente de que el `console.log` tiene esa finalidad pero nunca había visto que lo usaran así. Muchas gracias, @Pablo Lozano!

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada y así la pregunta quedará "respondida"

Answer (score 0):

Si lo hará, aunque no de la forma más optimizada ya que recorrerá uno a uno el array "a" comparándolo solo con 1 elemento filtrado por la función filter... Si entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer, creo que lo óptimo sería que solo dejaras el filter. Espero esto ayude!

Comment: Hola eyrockscript, gracias por tu colaboración, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada.

Comment: Gracias @MarcePuente , lo reviso.